# (JAVA) Selenium - Could not find / detect element in while loop

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need help in JAVA Selenium. I could not get the web driver to find the element I want in a while loop. I tried to do it without while loop, it would work. However without the while loop, I could not make the web driver to reload the page while waiting for the element to load. I would really appreciate if anyone could assist me in this.

The problem with my code is it will not exit the loop since **elementProgress** is forever **FALSE** because the web driver is not detecting the button thus not updating the **elementProgress** boolean value.

```
//check if progress button exist
boolean elementProgress;
elementProgress = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr:nth-child(1) .iconLabel")).size() != 0;

//auto reload page to prevent webpage timeout
while (!elementProgress) {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(15);
    driver.navigate().refresh();
    boolean check_dl_queue = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".cell > .table .total_records")).size() != 0;
    if (!check_dl_queue) {
        driver.navigate().refresh();
    }
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    driver.navigate().refresh();
    elementProgress = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr:nth-child(1) .iconLabel")).size() != 0;
    System.out.println("P2:" + elementProgress); //to printout element status
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? How could you find the element without the while loop (if you can, please attach the corresponding code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found a solution to that, haven't got time to post it here. Below are the the solution.

```
//boo stat for while loop
boolean elementProgress = true;
boolean elementProgress2 = true;

//setup new web driver wait
WebDriverWait dl_wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

//auto reload page to prevent webpage timeout
while (elementProgress) {
    driver.navigate().refresh();
    
    //start button click
    try {
        //phase 1: wait for button 1, if exceed wait time goto exception
        dl_wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("tr:nth-child(1) .iconLabel")));
        retryingFindClick(By.cssSelector("tr:nth-child(1) .iconLabel"));

        //phase 2: refresh page after button successfully clicked
        driver.navigate().refresh();

        //phase 3: wait for button 2, if exceed wait time goto exception
        while(elementProgress2) {
            try {
                dl_wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("tr:nth-child(1) .icon-cancel")));
                retryingFindClick(By.cssSelector("tr:nth-child(1) .icon-cancel"));
                
                //exit elementProgress2 while loop
                elementProgress2 = false;
                
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                //refresh page to counter false positive element not found exception
                driver.navigate().refresh();
            }
        }
        
        //exit elementProgress while loop
        elementProgress = false;

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        //refresh page to counter false positive element not found exception
        driver.navigate().refresh();
    }
}

public boolean retryingFindClick(By by) {
    boolean result = false;
    int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 2) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(by).click();
            result = true;
            break;
        } catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) {
        }
        attempts++;
    }
    return result;
}
```